# How to get the properties of the 'resize' event from the ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, dom-events, ngx-datatable, custom-events

I have created an event handler for the [resize event](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/outputs#resize) for the [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) in Angular 10. It seems to trigger correctly, but how do i get to the actual properties?

The output payload (i.e. properties) of the event is

```
{
  column,
  newValue
}
```

but where are they? I have displayed the event in chrome's dev tools, it seems to fire when the data table is resized (i.e. a column width changes), and the Event parameter is displayed along with the properties, but where are the *column* and *newValue* values?

I've downloaded the source code of the [demos](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/) and gone thru the source code and can't seem to find anything.

[image]

My code snippets are like:

**Angular Template**

```
...
  <div>
    <ngx-datatable #myTable (resize)="onColumnResize($event)">
        <ngx-datatable-column
          ...
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column
          ...
        </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ngx-datatable>
  </div>
...
```

**Component**

```
export class ResponsiveComponent {
  constructor( private renderer : Renderer2) {
    ...
  }

  onColumnResize(resizeEvent) {
    console.log(resizeEvent);
  }

}
```

I've effectively been modifying the [Responsive](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#responsive) example (not that that should really matter). I've also tried `console.log(resizeEvent.column)` and a few other variants but the browser dev tools says that it is undefined.

My setup is Chrome 87 (up to date) and as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with latest available version and event seems to be emited correctly. Please refer the sample implementation at [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ardinghelli-gp3my)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to display that data! Is your screenshot from the browser dev tools? If so, which one? Did you have some setting on? I have tried this is Chrome and Firefox and it is triggering and I'm getting the 'Event' data - but I cant see that 'column' property/object. How did u view it? I have also run your example, but the CodeSandbox console (and my local browser console) doesn't seem to trigger the event (i.e. I cant see the console.log in the 'onResize (event)' handler)

Comment: you may directly access the application at https://gp3my.csb.app/ and check the console getting logged.

Comment: Hi @Lambo12.I launched gp3my.csb.app in a new Chrome tab, opened the console in the Dev Tools on that tab, but when resizing the window the event doesn't seem to fire when doing the resize. The same occurs in the Firefox Browser Console.

Comment: I don't have firefox but tested it in chrome, it does emit event whenever column size is resized

Comment: Thankyou for confirming that. Im absolutely stumped on this one. I'm on Windows 7. I'll will try some different OSs maybe a nix distro of some sort, Safari and an android phone.